# Close completing-read dialog before continuing

Tags: completing-read

I've written an elisp script to automate the process of taking screenshots. The script uses [maim](https://github.com/naelstrof/maim) and [imgur.sh](https://github.com/tremby/imgur.sh). Not really important however. Here is the code:

```lisp
;;; ../../.local/share/git/dotArch/.config/doom/userconfig/screenshot.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun db/screenshot ()
  "Interactive menu for screenshots. Requires main, xsel, xclip and curl to be installed."
  (interactive)

  (let* ((actions '("Section" "Whole Screen"))
        (targets '("Imgur" "Clipboard" "Locally"))

        ;; The default extension used for images.
        (ext "png")

        ;; The default temporary directory used to store images.
        (tmp-dir "/tmp/")

        ;; The default temporary name used for images.
        (tmp-name "screenshot")

        ;; The full file path to a temporary image.
        (tmp-file (concat tmp-dir tmp-name "." ext)))

    (setq action (completing-read "Take screenshot of ..." actions )
          target (completing-read "Save screenshot ..." targets ))
    (setq result (db/screenshot-return-cmd action target tmp-file ext))
    (call-process-shell-command (nth 1 result) nil nil nil)
    (cond ((equal target "Locally")
           (message (concat "Image will be saved to: " (nth 0 result))))
          ((equal target "Imgur")
           (message "Image will be uploaded to Imgur. URL will be saved to the clipboard."))
          ((equal target "Clipboard")
           (message "Image will be saved to the clipboard.")))))

(defun db/screenshot-return-cmd (source target tmp-file ext)
  "Build the command to be executed for taking screenshots."
  (let ((cmd ""))
    (cond ((equal source "Section")
           (cond ((equal target "Locally")
                  (print "section local")
                  (setq tmp-file (concat (read-directory-name "Select directory: " "~/") (read-string "File name (Without extension): ") "." ext))
                  (setq cmd (concat "maim -s " tmp-file)))
                 ((equal target "Imgur")
                  (setq cmd (concat "maim -s " tmp-file "; imgur " tmp-file " | xclip -selection clipboard")))
                 ((equal target "Clipboard")
                  (setq cmd (concat "maim -s | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png")))))
          ((equal source "Whole Screen")
           (cond ((equal target "Locally")
                  (setq tmp-file (concat (read-directory-name "Select directory: " "~/") (read-string "File name (Without extension): ") "." ext))
                  (setq cmd (concat "maim " tmp-file)))
                 ((equal target "Imgur")
                  (setq cmd (concat "maim " tmp-file "; imgur " tmp-file " | xclip -selection clipboard")))
                 ((equal target "Clipboard")
                  (setq cmd (concat "maim | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png"))))))
    (list tmp-file cmd)))
```

I'm still a noob with elisp, so any suggestions regarding my code are welcome.

I use `completing-read` to ask the user what he wants to screenshot and where to save it (For example 1: Whole screen, 2: Upload to imgur):

```lisp
;; ...
    (setq action (completing-read "Take screenshot of ..." actions )
          target (completing-read "Save screenshot ..." targets ))
;; ...
```

After that I execute the corresponding command using `maim`. However the problem is that the second `completing-read`-dialog, where the user selects the target is still visible when maim takes the screenshot, resulting in something like this:

[image: Dialog still visible]

I hope you get my problem. I want the `completing-read` to close before I take the screenshot. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: You could try using [`sit-for`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Waiting.html) after you get the user's respond from `completing-read` but before you actually take the screenshot.

Comment: @Dan It worked! Thanks. Unfortunately I think I can't upvote your comment (because I'm too new)?

Comment: No problem.  I added it as an answer post instead.  Glad it worked!

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option you have is to use
the
[`sit-for`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Waiting.html) function
after you get the user's response, but before you take the actual screenshot.